# How to pre-load and share a 3rd party JavaScript library across multiple LWCs?

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, libraries, third-party

[This example](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/libsD3/libsD3.js) of using [D3](https://d3js.org/) combines the `loadScript` in the `connectedCallback` with the code that uses D3, `initializeD3` here:

```
renderedCallback() {
    ...
    Promise.all([
        loadScript(this, D3 + '/d3.v5.min.js'),
        loadStyle(this, D3 + '/style.css')
    ])
        .then(() => {
            this.initializeD3();
        })
    ...
}
```

I want to use [JEXL](https://github.com/TomFrost/Jexl) in multiple components so ideally would just like to `import` a reference to it where needed and ideally have it pre-cached before first use. (JEXL is working fine inside LWCs.)

What does that look like in LWCs?

Comment: Take a look at https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/297645/how-to-load-external-module-lib-once-and-make-it-global-for-spa-application

Comment: Thanks Alba. Perhaps there is no elegant solution to this...